# What is state 123 for error 18456 on an Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure Webjob that can't connect to the database with the error "login failed for user". (Incidentally, the Web App uses the same connection string to connect without a problem).

Here are the details from the error log:

```
    Error code: 18456
    Error state: 123
```

I can't find any documentation on state 123. Can anyone tell me what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some help from the Microsoft guys and they've updated the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error

States 122 - 124 means "Failure due to empty user name or password."

Answer (score 0):

We don't document the error state codes because they don't mean anything.  They represent unique instances of an error in out code base to help us debug customer issues faster.  So, it more or less maps to line x in source code file y.

Thanks,
Conor Cunningham
Architect, SQL Core Engine

Answer (score 0):

Error 18456 is a generic connection error and may have many causes. I would not pay too much attention to 123 
Thanks,
Mirek

Comment: To figure out the cause of the error 18456, you need to look at the state number. From the documentation: "...in the SQL Server error log, a corresponding error contains an error state that maps to an authentication failure condition. Compare the error state to the following list to determine the reason for the login failure." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error
My issue was that state 123 wasn't documented but the nice Microsoft people have now done that.